# HAXM won't work on WINDOWS 10 14393 build

Tags: android, windows-10, intel, haxm

I have installed HAXM v6.0.3 and android studio 2.1 on windows 10 latest build 14393. The HAXM driver doesn't seem to work when driver signature check is enforced. Works only in Enforced disable signature check. What do I do now?

Comment: Its funny none answered, anyways, it was due to bad signature file embedded in HAXM, it was fixed in future releases. Update the HAXM.